# Shell script : replacing and adding characters in a string

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

I am new to shell scripting and having trouble doing following:

I have this:

```
MY_MACR0_VALUE="123ABCD"
```

I want to convert it to this:

```
#define MY_MACR0_VALUE "123ABCD"
```

I am doing this:

```
//that string is coming from command line 

    newvar=$(echo "$1" | tr '=' ' ') 

    echo "#define $newvar" >> MacroFile.h
```

I am getting this:

```
#define MY_MACR0_VALUE 123ABCD
```

instead of

```
#define MY_MACR0_VALUE "123ABCD"
```

**The double quotes are missing.**

How can I fix my script to get the desired result?

**EDIT**

I may also have some non valued Macros from the commandline , like

`INCLUDE_SOMETHING`

which should be changed to

`#define INCLUDE_SOMETHING`

So I dont need to change anything in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, shell is stripping out the quotes so the script does not even see them. You can use your script if you escape the quotes in the argument:

```
sh script.sh MY_MACR0_VALUE=\"123ABCD\"
```

Or you can use this line in the script:

```
echo "#define $(sed '/=/{s/=/ "/;s/$/"/}' <<< $1)" >> MacroFile.h
```

Comment: It fixed the issue for `#define MY_MACR0_VALUE "123ABCD"`  but i have some Macros to be passed in the commandline which wont have any value for eg: `#define INCLUDE_SOMEFILE` , your solution is corrupting them by adding an extra " at their end like this `#define INCLUDE_SOMEFILE"`. My bad I missed to mention it in question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed`. Like this:

```
sed 's/\([^=]*\)=\(.*\)/#define \1 \2/' <<< "$1"
```

Output:

```
#define MY_MACR0_VALUE "123ABCD"
```

The command obtains the part before and after the `=` into separate capturing groups and populates them to the final string.

Answer (score 0):

`sed` solution without using capturing groups,

```
sed 's/^/#define /g;s/=/ /g' <<< "$1"
```

Example:

```
$ echo 'MY_MACR0_VALUE="123ABCD"' | sed 's/^/#define /g;s/=/ /g'
#define MY_MACR0_VALUE "123ABCD"
```

Explanation:

- `s/^/#define /g` Adds `#define` at the starting.
- `s/=/ /` Replaces `=` sign with space.

Answer (score 0):

`awk -F "=" '{print "#define",$1,$2}' <<< "$1"`

Field separator is no shown so it removed the `=` and prints the first and second part with #define before them